# Aligning Some NavigationMenuItems to the Right in the NavigationMenu

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, radix-ui, shadcnui

I'm working with the `NavigationMenu` component and I'm trying to achieve a specific layout where some `NavigationMenuItem`s are aligned to the left of the screen, while others (such as login and theme change options) are aligned to the right. I'm unsure of the best practices for accomplishing this with the `NavigationMenu` component.

Is there a recommended way to position some `NavigationMenuItem`s to the right side of the screen? I'm looking for a solution that aligns with the intended use of the component and maintains accessibility and responsiveness.

Thank you in advance for your guidance!

Here is my current code:

```js
  return (
    <NavigationMenu>
      <NavigationMenuList>
        <NavigationMenuItem>
          <NavigationMenuTrigger>Getting started</NavigationMenuTrigger>
          <NavigationMenuContent>
            <ul className="grid gap-3 p-6 md:w-[400px] lg:w-[500px] lg:grid-cols-[.75fr_1fr]">
              <li className="row-span-3">
                <NavigationMenuLink asChild>
                  <a
                    className="flex h-full w-full select-none flex-col justify-end rounded-md bg-gradient-to-b from-muted/50 to-muted p-6 no-underline outline-none focus:shadow-md"
                    href="/"
                  >
                    <div className="mb-2 mt-4 text-lg font-medium">
                      shadcn/ui
                    </div>
                    <p className="text-sm leading-tight text-muted-foreground">
                      Beautifully designed components that you can copy and
                      paste into your apps. Accessible. Customizable. Open
                      Source.
                    </p>
                  </a>
                </NavigationMenuLink>
              </li>
              <ListItem href="/docs" title="Introduction">
                Re-usable components built using Radix UI and Tailwind CSS.
              </ListItem>
              <ListItem href="/docs/installation" title="Installation">
                How to install dependencies and structure your app.
              </ListItem>
              <ListItem href="/docs/primitives/typography" title="Typography">
                Styles for headings, paragraphs, lists...etc
              </ListItem>
            </ul>
          </NavigationMenuContent>
        </NavigationMenuItem>
        <NavigationMenuItem>
          <NavigationMenuTrigger>Components</NavigationMenuTrigger>
          <NavigationMenuContent>
            <ul className="grid w-[400px] gap-3 p-4 md:w-[500px] md:grid-cols-2 lg:w-[600px] ">
              {components.map((component) => (
                <ListItem
                  key={component.title}
                  title={component.title}
                  href={component.href}
                >
                  {component.description}
                </ListItem>
              ))}
            </ul>
          </NavigationMenuContent>
        </NavigationMenuItem>
        <NavigationMenuItem>
          <Link href="/docs" legacyBehavior passHref>
            <NavigationMenuLink className={navigationMenuTriggerStyle()}>
              Documentation
            </NavigationMenuLink>
          </Link>
        </NavigationMenuItem>
        {/* Conditional rendering based on login state */}
        {isLoggedIn ? (
          <NavigationMenuItem>
            <Button onClick={signOutFunction} className="">
              Cerrar sesión
            </Button>
          </NavigationMenuItem>
        ) : (
          <>
            <NavigationMenuItem>
              <Button
                onClick={() => router.push("/iniciar-sesion")}
                className=""
              >
                Iniciar Sesión
              </Button>
            </NavigationMenuItem>
            <NavigationMenuItem>
              <Button onClick={() => router.push("/crear-cuenta")} className="">
                Crear Cuenta
              </Button>
            </NavigationMenuItem>
          </>
        )}
        {/* Mode Toggle as a NavigationMenuItem for consistency */}
        <NavigationMenuItem>
          <ModeToggle />
        </NavigationMenuItem>
      </NavigationMenuList>
    </NavigationMenu>
  );
```

Comment: Can you please create a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/) snippet?

Comment: @RokBenko Hi Rok! Apologies for the delay, and thank you for the answer. I've created a simplified version of my navigation bar in StackBlitz to illustrate the issue I'm facing with aligning the login buttons to the right side of the navbar. Here's the link to the StackBlitz project: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-xzhzvb . If you need any more information to help me solve my issue, please let me know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following CSS:

```
ul {
  width: 100vw; // Make it full-screen wide
  display: flex; // Necessary for flex-grow to work
}

li:nth-child(2) {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

The key here is that you need to add `flex-grow: 1` to the last `<li>` you want to keep on the left side. In the case of your StackBlitz snippet, it's the second `<li>`.

See the forked [StackBlitz snippet](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-t6dfbu?file=app%2Fglobals.css).

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I am really bad with css but trying to learn :)

Comment: You're welcome. We all have to start somewhere. :)

Comment: It worked almost perfectly, but I encountered an overflow issue with width: 100vw; on the right elements of the navbar. To resolve this, I adjusted the width to 99vw; which helped to eliminate the overflow. Additionally, applying overflow-hidden to <NavigationMenu className="flex w-full overflow-hidden"> also contributed to resolving the issue, although it slightly cropped the buttons on the right. I'm sharing these modifications here for anyone else following this thread and looking for solutions to similar challenges. :)